# How to set and update the datepicker in Javafx to a maximum of 2 months?

Tags: java, javafx, datepicker

```java
DepatureD.setDayCellFactory(datePicker -> new DateCell(){
    public void updateItem(LocalDate date, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(date, empty);
        LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();

        setDisable(empty || date.compareTo(today) > 0 );
    }
});
```

This is the code that I used to prevent the selection of past dates in DatePicker. I'm trying to find out how to set the date the range to 2 months from the present date and update it as the days go by.

Comment: Actually,  this code disables the selection of future days not past.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you can limit a `DatePicker` with a date range:

```java
datePicker.setDayCellFactory(param -> new DateCell() {
    private LocalDate now = LocalDate.now();
    private LocalDate twoMonthsLater = LocalDate.now().plusMonths(2);

    @Override
    public void updateItem(LocalDate date, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(date, empty);
        if (date != null && !empty) {
            setDisable(date.compareTo(now) < 0 || date.compareTo(twoMonthsLater) > 0);
        }
    }
});
```